# Predicates not pushed down to all tables in Spark join (on parquet files)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a view, where I join multiple tables. The view has a where clause. But this is only pushed to one of the tables that are joined. The other tables are fully loaded.

Is there a way to push the where clause to all parquet files read?

**EDIT:**

The join looks something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW v_test as SELECT * 
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 
ON (t1.c1 = t2. c1)

LEFT JOIN t3
ON (t1.c1 = t3.c1)
```

When i now do:

```
SELECT * FROM v_test WHERE c5 = 0
```

The predicate `c5 equals 0` is only pushed down to the parquet files of table `t1`. I can see this from the explain plan. Table `t2` and `t3` are fully scanned.

Comment: Could you add an appropriate example here, so that the problem statement is clear? You should refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: could you also mention which spark version are you running?

Comment: which table column `c5` belongs to?

Comment: all tables have column `c5`